# Swift Google Maps get coordinates from json

Tags: ios, json, xcode, swift, google-maps

I'm trying to show markers with coordinates from a json server.

I am using this code to get the coordinates:

```
    let query = PFQuery(className:"locations")
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects:[PFObject]?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
    if error == nil {
            for object in objects! {
                self.long = object["longitude"] as! Double
                self.lat = object["latitude"] as! Double
                print(self.lat, self.long)

            }
        } else {
            print(error)
        }
    }
```

I get this result from **print(self.lat, self.long)**

```
39.570355 2.679148
39.570364 2.687386
39.569988 2.691598
39.569756 2.695900
```

I use this to show it on the map:

```
marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(self.lat, self.long)
```

Now I want to loop this results and first show the first row with coordinates on the map, and when I touch a button I want it to show the next row. Is that possible in some way? I can't figure out how to do it.

Comment: save the coordinates into an array and have an index for it, then in the button action, take the coordinate at index from the array and add the marker - oh and increase the index.

Comment: Okey, I will try that.

Answer (score 0):

firstly you should create two arrays one for Latitude and another for longitude . latitude and longitude values taken from your example

```
var latitudeArr : NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()
var longitudeArr : NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()

    let lat1 : Double = 63.82869
    let lat2 : Double = 63.828743
    let lat3 : Double = 63.828528
    let lat4 : Double = 63.82862

    latitudeArr = NSMutableArray(array: [lat1,lat2,lat3,lat4])

    let long1 : Double = 20.263622
    let long2 : Double = 20.264524
    let long3 : Double = 20.263274
    let long4 : Double = 20.264034

    longitudeArr = NSMutableArray(array: [long1,long2,long3,long4])
```

Now you have to run a loop for setting annotion on mapView

```
for index in 0...3 {

    let annotation: MKPointAnnotation = MKPointAnnotation()
    annotation.title = "name"
    let latitude: Double = latitudeArr.objectAtIndex(index) as! Double
    let longitude: Double = longitudeArr.objectAtIndex(index) as! Double
    annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude)
    self.mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)

    }
```

surely it will work for you

Comment: Why do dou propose two arrays?

Comment: and this isn't what he wants either... my comment describes that... he only wants 1 marker and alter it based on button press

Comment: Now I use this code to get an array: let locationCoordinates = NSMutableArray(arrayLiteral: object["longitude"], object["latitude"])   And get this result:   (

    ”2.679148”,

    ”39.570355"

)

(

    ”2.687386”,

    ”39.570364"

)

(

    ”2.691598”,

    ”39.569988"

)

(

    ”2.695900”,

    ”39.569756"

)  Is it possible to use the above code to loop in this array?